# How to make android app compatible with all versions of android?

Tags: android, facebook

My Android application has an integration with Facebook API.
The Facebook API is working properly in mobile with Android 5.0(Lollipop) but it's not opening in Android 7.0(Noughat) mobile.
Please help.

Comment: Maybe you should also check the version of Facebook API you are using, and cross reference that to the supported Android versions.

Comment: Where should we check the version of Facebook API in the Android application?

Comment: Check the error in logcat while you trying to open the app in Android 7.0 device.

Comment: okay..thank you Tim & Febi for the help.

Comment: can you please show the logcat error?

Comment: Actually the problem occurs when Facebook application is installed in mobile.In that case my app is not able to login into Facebook.